# PythonCV2 NoneType Object

Tags: python, opencv, nonetype

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
 Usage:
./ssearch.py input_image (f|q)
 f=fast, q=quality
 Use "l" to display less rects, 'm' to display more rects, "q" to quit.
 '''

import sys
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
# If image path and f/q is not passed as command
# line arguments, quit and display help message
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print(__doc__)
    sys.exit(1)

# speed-up using multithreads
cv2.setUseOptimized(True);
cv2.setNumThreads(4);
# read image
im = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
# resize image
newHeight = 200
newWidth = int(im.shape[1]*200/im.shape[0])
im = cv2.resize(im, (newWidth, newHeight))
```

Here i am getting error

```
AttributeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b88f466ecb3b> in <module>
     25     # resize image
     26     newHeight = 200
     --->  27     newWidth = int(im.shape[1]*200/im.shape[0])
     28     im = cv2.resize(im, (newWidth, newHeight))
     29 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

and explain cv2.imread(sys,argv[1]) line

(2)second question is how do i get nonetype error because i havent 
 passed my image  path from my command line yet
 (3) cmd line didnt prompt because program didnt executed with th error

i am sorry i couldnt place entire code

Comment: "If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL )." https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56

Comment: Did you check if the path to image is valid? Before reading image, try `os.path.exists(sys.argv[1])`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
# read image
im = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
if im == None :
    sys.exit('Invalid or missing image: ' + sys.argv[1])
```

BEFORE you try to do anything with your image `im`.

Comment: @sriharsha well, obviously you run it like `./script.py -f` and the script thinks that `-f` is a file name it should open.